# Android DataBinding LiveData - not notify changed in DialogFragment & BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I have an `BottomSheetDialogFragment` 's layout like this:

```
<data>

    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.sample.MyViewModel" />
</data>

<TextView android:id="@+id/tvValue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text='@{String.format("%.1f", viewModel.weight)}'/>

<Button android:id="@+id/cmdUpdate"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.updateWeight()}"
                android:text="@string/update" />
```

And here is the kotlin code:

```
  // MyViewModel
  val weight = MutableLiveData<Double>()
  fun updateWeight() {
     weight.value?.let {
        weight.value = (it + 0.1)
    }
  }

 // BottomSheetDialogFragment bind view model
 val myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(it, factory).get(MyViewModel::class)
 binding.viewModel = myViewModel

// code showing BottomSheet:
 val fragment = MyBottomSheetFragment()
 fragment.show(fragmentManager, "bottomsheet")
```

The first time open bottomsheet fragment, it can show the weight value, but *when I click on button to update weight, there is nothing happen*. From debugger, I can see that the `updateWeight` method is called, and the weight value is changed, but the `TextView` is not updated. This also happens on other DialogFragment.
The same code can work if I use normal `Fragment`
Is there something wrong with DialogFragment & DataBinding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call

```
binding.setLifecycleOwner(this)
```

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.html#setLifecycleOwner(android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner)), it allows to update your view when `LiveData` was changed.

Comment: Brilliant, I forgot this line on `DialogFragment` & `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. Thank you so much. It works now